# why dos my $(document).ready not work?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

my getall() function doesn't run when I load the page, but it dos run when I click the button, can somebody tell me why the  $(document).ready doesn't run right away?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 function getAll() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetComment",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (model) {

        alert("hello")
        },
        error: alert("eitthvað fór úskeiðis, reyndu aftur síðar"),
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
}

$("#button").click(function (evt) {
    var comment = document.getElementById('CommentText').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Index",
        data: { "CommentText": comment },
        success: function () {
            getAll();
            $("#CommentText").val("")

        },
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
    evt.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: You should call your function to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling it, but just defining; call it after its definition like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getAll() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetComment",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (model) {

                alert("hello")
            },
            error: alert("eitthvað fór úskeiðis, reyndu aftur síðar"),
            dataType: "JSON"
        });
    }

    getAll();

    $("#button").click(function (evt) {
        var comment = document.getElementById('CommentText').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Index",
            data: {
                "CommentText": comment
            },
            success: function () {
                getAll();
                $("#CommentText").val("")

            },
            dataType: "JSON"
        });
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call your function inside the `$(document).ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 function getAll() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetComment",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (model) {

        alert("hello")
        },
        error: alert("eitthvað fór úskeiðis, reyndu aftur síðar"),
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
  getAll()//Call your function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document ready function is working, but you're not actually calling the function. You need to add

`getAll()`

After somewhere in your `ready` function

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getAll() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetComment",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (model) {

        alert("hello")
        },
        error: alert("eitthvað fór úskeiðis, reyndu aftur síðar"),
        dataType: "JSON"
    });

$(function(){

getAll();

});
```